# I am not able to update/create package-lock.json

Tags: angular, jenkins, build, npm-install, package-lock.json

I updated the `package.json` file to move from angualar 6 to angular7. When I finished running `npm install` the node modules were updated and the application was running in my local as expected. But, the jenkins build is failing for some reason. After some research came to know that `package-lock.json` was not getting updated after `npm install`.

My expectation was that the `package-lock.json` should create/update when we do `npm install`. Correct me if I am wrong? So, I deleted the file and re-ran the command once again expecting a new `package-lock.json` file and still not create/updated. I tried checking `.npmrc`  and don't see any `package-lock.json` property but, having `shrinkwrap=false` in the file.

Is there any other reason this is not working?

Comment: Can you share what your .npmrc file looks like? (Hide any confidential information please)

Comment: what version of node and npm?

Comment: this is my .npmrc file. Hope this helps(not included other fields which are sensitive)                  always-auth=true
strict-ssl=false
shrinkwrap=false

and I am using below versions  npm = 6.4.1 and node= 10.15.3

Comment: @Bharath did you find the cause or a solution to this problem?